Is tflite C API thread-safe?
I am using tflite C API in golang with CGO. Using multiple go routines to call the following functions

TfLiteModelCreate
TfLiteInterpreterCreate
TfLiteInterpreterInvoke

Wanted to know if these are thread safe, in which I would have to use locks? The documentation does not talk about the thread safety.
